# Windows Powershell: open at specific location

Tags: windows-10, powershell

As shown below, I place my taskbar at the left edge of screen, and tried to set Powershell windows to be at 100,100 from the top, left but it stuck be at the (0,0) no matter how many times I tried. How can I configure to make PowerShell windows start at the position I want?
// update: Finally, I got it, 
when I open the PowerShell windows from Run command / powershell , it show as setting in `default` tab, but when I alt x and chose PowerShell or PowerShell Admin, I show the "default" power shell 
[image]
[image]
[image: open PS from Run / powershell]
[image: open from alt x]

Comment: It seems like it's at the `100,100` position with the height just being 9001 it may appear otherwise but it seems to be correct from the screen shot per those settings.

Comment: @ITSnuggles : did try to change to 500,500 but nothing happend :'(

Comment: 9001 is not a height really, it is the virtual buffer's height which can be scrolled within the height of 30. Both these are measured in lines, not pixels as the window position.

Comment: The window preview in your screen shots makes it clear that the window is supposed to be positioned differently depending on the setting...

Comment: You need to change the position using the defaults menu option. Settings only affects the current instance.

Comment: Ah.... I had an oversight, the 9001 is the screen buffer... my bad!! Try the other suggestions and see what results you get. If all else fails, start with a simple reboot and see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: I cannot replicate this.

Comment: thanks everyone for help, I finally got it, I updated the question to show answer with image.